# How to achieve high avaliability?

Tags: windows, message-queue, nservicebus

I'm about to build a new system and I want maximum availability! I'll have to use Windows!

I will have clients talking to my system using webservices. I'll also get data from surrounding systems. This data is delivered using messaging, MQ-series and MSMQ. 
The system will produce some data that is sent back to the surrounding systems using queues.

After new data has come to the system different processes will use this data to do diffrent tasks, like printing, writing to databases etc.

To achieve high availablity I'm planning to have two versions of the system running in parallel on two different machines. The clients will try to use the first server thats responds correctly.
I think an ideal soultion would be that the incomming data from anyone of the two servers is placed in a COMMON queue(on a third machine?). Data in the queue can be picked up by processes on both servers(think producer-consumer pattern).

I think that *maybe* **NServiceBus** will suits my needs. I have a few questions according to the above.

- Can a queue be shared between two servers? I dont want data to be stuck on a server if its gets down. I that case I want the other server to keep processing.
- Can two(or more) "consumers"/processes on different machines pick data from a common queue?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In short you will want to use the distributor... http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859556-load-balancing-with-the-distributor

The key thing here is that the distributor node is a single point of failure so you want to run it on a cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of NSB distributor is not to address availability issues but to address scale issues, distributors help scaling out systems at a low cost.

By looking at the description, your system consist of WebService endpoits, multiple databases and queuing infrastructure. If you want to achieve complete high-availability you will have to make sure there are no single points of failures. In order to do that you will need,

1. A load balanced web farm for web service endpoints (2 or more servers)
2. Application cluster for queues and applications that relies on those queues.
3. Highly available database server, again clustered.
4. On top of everything a good SAN.

But if you are referring to being available to consumers, you just have to make sure target queues and webservice endpoints are available. And making sure the overall architecture promotes deferred execution.

Two or more applications can read a MSMQ queue remotely but thats something you don't want to do since it's based on DTC. And that's a real performance killer.

Some references

- [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2012/05/01/10299698.aspx][1]
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx][2]